# dim ws as worksheet set ws=ActiveSheet gives me "Type Mismatch"

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to have a modelless form that does something to current worksheet.
Everything works fine when I use it on the worksheets in the same workbook where the form is defined. (ActiveSheet represents current worksheet).

The problem happens when I try to use form when there is different active workbook, when I click on a form it immediately activates the workbook where it was defined and ActiveSheet no longer works for me. It acts strange:

```
dim ws as worksheet
set ws=ActiveSheet
```

gives me "Type Mismatch"

```
debug.print ActiveSheet.Name ' prints the name of the original worksheet
debug.print ActiveSheet.Parent.Name ' prints the name of the workbook where form is defined
```

This is Excel 2013.
I think I was able to do it in previous versions. Has this ability been lost?

Comment: According to [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel._workbook.activesheet.aspx), ActiveSheet returns an `object`.  You probably need a cast.

Comment: try `Application.ActiveSheet`

Comment: Don't use `ActiveSheet`. Use `Sheet1` or `Sheets("Sheet1")` instead. What happens when a sheet is not active?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will occur if a **Chart** or other non-worksheet is *Active*

Comment: Thanks this explains the error I was getting. The chart was, indeed, active.

Answer (score 3):

```
Dim ws as worksheet
Set ws= ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet
```